# Dynamic Controls doesn't work well with IE8

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-8, htmlgenericcontrol

I work in Microsoft .NET 4.0 environment.   I have a list of variable number of pictures with their titles, to write to screen, so, I use dynamic controls in codebehind of ASP.NET.

I wrote the following code:

For each of the pictures in the list I define:

label control:

```
Label lbPic = new Label();
lbPic.Text = "PicTitle";
```

Picture control:

```
ImageButton ImgPic = new ImageButton();
ImgPic.ID = "imgID";
ImgPic.CssClass = "myImgCSS";
ImgPic.ImageUrl = "myImgUrl";
```

HTML control to include both label and picture:

```
HtmlGenericControl hgc = new HtmlGenericControl("myDivName");
hgc.Controls.Add(lbPic);
hgc.Controls.Add(imgPic);
hgc.Attributes.Add("class", "myHgcCss");
```

Each picture (the img+lable pair) is included in:

```
dvPhotos.Controls.Add(hgc);
```

`dvPhotos` is defined in the .aspx file, 
as ID of a `<div>`. This div is defined with `runat="server"`.

The pictures look fine in FireFox, Chrome, and IE9.  They look very bad in IE8.

It seems that the HTML control ignores "myHgcCss", so all the pictures and labels are put in a mess in `dvPhotos`.

Any idea why it doesn't work with IE8?

The CSS relevant part:

```
.myHgcCss
{
    float:right;
    height: 180px;
    width:  170px;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    color:#003300;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    font-size:15px;
    font-style:normal;
    text-align:right;
}
.myImgCSS
{
    height: 150px;
    width:  150px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you put the `hgc.Attributes.Add("class", "myHgcCss");` before the `hgc.Controls.Add` lines?  It sounds like a problem with how Firefox vs IE8 caches content.  This site talks about these kinds of bugs with HtmlGenericControl and IE8: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/252507-Problem-with-HTMLAnchor-and-ASPNet-Cache

Comment: Please, can you post the relevant part of the .css file?

Comment: I tried to change the places, it makes no difference...

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's a bug in IE8, this might be a work around.  Instead of doing this:

```
dvPhotos.Controls.Add(hgc);
```

Add the hgc to the header.  Something like this:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(hgc);
```

Read this, I think he found a work around to your same problem:

https://siderite.dev/blog/controls-collection-cannot-be-modified.html